# Custom Payment Gateway integration in joomla registration form

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, subscriptions, membership, payment-gateway

I have installed Joomla 3.5. There are a default joomla registration form, image as follows:

[image: Joomla Registration Form]

So I want to integrate Pay-u-money payment gateway and users should enter card details in the same registration form before "Register" buttom. Image as given below:
[image: Payment Form]

Any help ?

Comment: What is the question? Please be specific and show us what you have tried (For example, include code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer will reflect the specificity of your "question."  You need to create to a user plugin and listen to the onContentPrepareForm event so you can inject your custom fields, making sure the context is com_users.registration.  Then u need to hook into the onUserAfterSave or onUserBeforeSave event to capture the entered data and save.

A point of caution, I highly recommend you do not save customer credit card data in your Joomla database.  You are exposing yourself and your customers to unnecessary liabilities in addition to a whole host of regulatory requirements when dealing with financial data.

If you do not simply transfer the client credit card data to your 3rd party payment platform and save a customer reference number for later access, you need to seriously reconsider the vendor you're using!

[Joomla Plugin Events](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events)

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this I've used 3rd party extensions such as Fabrik and ChronoForms to create a custom registration form with a payment plug-in.

Check the sites for these extensions to see if they support Pay-u-money, I know a lot of payment processors are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to complement and extend this with one extension, in this case you can find some options in the Extensions Directory, here you have the main category:

- [Membership & Subscriptions](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions)

Two popular extensions are [Membership Pro](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/membership-pro) and [PayPlans](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/payplans).

---

*I am not affiliated with any of the extensions mentioned*